# pip - What is the difference between `pip install djangorestframework` and `pip install django_rest_framework`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I would like to install Django REST framework.

I saw `pip install djangorestframework` at [its official docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/), but saw different one at [a tutorial website](https://radixweb.com/blog/create-rest-api-using-django-rest-framework), which says `pip install django_rest_framework`.

What are the differences between them?

Comment: Can you also update your question with the link to the docs too?

Comment: The second one is a package that does no more than declaring a dependency on the first one. It will install the Django REST Framework indirectly.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I updated the question by adding each link, thank you

Comment: @KlausD. Excuse me, what do you mean by "... It will install the Django REST Framework indirectly"? I don't get it..

Answer (score 2):

The [django-rest-framework](https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-framework/) is the an alias name of the project. When you click on the homepage, it redirect you to the official site [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) where the command for installing the package is `pip install djangorestframework`.

I tried in a fresh virtual env the command `pip install django_rest_framework` and it installs the last version of the django rest framework.

```
asgiref-3.7.2 django-5.0 django-rest-framework-0.1.0 djangorestframework-3.14.0 pytz-2023.3.post1 sqlparse-0.4.4
```

With the alias, you can't target a dedicated version, it will always target the latest version.

```
python3 -m pip install django-rest-framework==3.12.4
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-rest-framework==3.12.4 (from versions: 0.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-rest-framework==3.12.4
```

---

One important point, you are right to check the name of the package, you could have some typo squatting leading to malicious packages (like describe in this [blog article](https://snyk.io/fr/blog/malicious-packages-found-to-be-typo-squatting-in-pypi/)).

Comment: So, do `pip install djangorestframework` and `pip install django_rest_framework` install the last version of the django rest framework? In other words, they are same, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, but you can't choose the version with django_rest_framework (I edit my post with this precision).